# Projection of 3D vector on an axis, provided two projection are known.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Suppose $ x$ and $y$ are the unit vector on $x$-axis and $y$-axis respectively, $a$ is a vector on the $xy$-plane and $b$ is the vector on $xyz$-cube := $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Further suppose that the following angles are known $ x \angle a, a \angle b, x \angle b$ where $ a \angle b$ is the angle between the minor arc defined by $ a$ and $b$ in the $ab$-plane.  In other words, we know every angle between $a,x,b$.

**Can we write $ b \angle y = f(x \angle a, a \angle b, x \angle b)$ for some function $f$?**

Equivalently, can we write down the coordinates of $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$? The first coordinate is given by $b \cos x \angle b$, the $z$-coordinate can be found by Pythagoras, provided the $y$-coordinate is known.

**So the problem boils down to finding the $\mathrm{proj}_y b$ provided $\mathrm{proj}_x b$ and $\mathrm{proj}_a b$ is known for some $a$ in $xy$-plane.**

Comment: What is $xyz$-plane?

Comment: @user Sorry, I meant $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the direction of the vector $b$ is completely determined (up to the sign of projection on the axis $z$) by the given angles $x\angle a=\gamma$, $b\angle x=\alpha$, $b\angle a=\beta$.

Let $(x,y,z)$ be the coordinates of the unit vector $\hat b$ be  in the direction of $b$ and the corresponding unit vectors in the other directions be
$\hat x=(1,0,0)$ and $\hat a=(\cos\gamma,\sin\gamma,0)$.

Then we have $\cos\alpha=\hat b\cdot\hat x=x$ and $\cos\beta=\hat b\cdot\hat a=x\cos\gamma+y\sin\gamma$.

Resolving this system of equations one obtains:
$$
y=\frac{\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma}.\tag1
$$

To obtain $\mathrm{proj}_y b$ for a vector $b$ with an arbitrary length just multiply the above expression by $\frac{\mathrm{proj}_x b}{\cos\alpha}$.